# For $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_m$ in a $R$-vector space, can there exist $\alpha$ such that $(\alpha,\alpha_i)>0,\forall 1\le i\le m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

The question is:

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space and dim$V$=n. It has an inner product $(,)$.

Let $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_m\in V$.

They satisfy that if there exists non-negative real numbers $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots ,\lambda_m$ such that $\lambda_1\alpha_1+\lambda_2\alpha_2+\cdots+\lambda_m\alpha_m=0$,
it must be $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\cdots=\lambda_m=0$.

I want to proof that there exists $\alpha\in V$ such that $(\alpha,\alpha_i)>0,\forall~1\le i\le m$.

My attempt is :

Use induction on m.

If m=1, it is trivial.

Suppose when m-1,it holds.So there exists $\beta_1$ such that $ (\beta_1,\alpha_j)>0,\forall~1\le j\le m-1$.

Let W=span{$\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_{m-1}$}, W is closed .${\alpha_m}$ is a convex set and compact.

Using the Hahn-Banach theorem, there exists $\beta_2$ such that $(\beta_2,\alpha_m)>0$ and $(\beta_2,\alpha_j)=0,\forall 1\le j\le m-1$.

Then  considering $\beta_2+\beta_1$. If necessary, we can multiply $\beta_2$  by a positive coefficient.

But this is wrong, because $W\cap$ {$\alpha_m$} may not be empty.

I want to solve the problem or get some hints.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "they satisfy", it seems that you are requiring this property (that is not possessed by general sets of vectors alpha). Then, what do you want to prove? Please, clearly state "I want to prove that...".

Comment: @Doriano Brogioli Thanks, I have edited it.

Comment: This is Gordan theorem.